# how to create individual i18next instances for different users on node server?

Tags: node.js, i18next

I am new to node.js. I am using `i18next` for internationalization in my node application. here is the code 
utils.js

```
i18n.use(Backend).init({
  debug: true,
  load: ['ar','en'],
  fallbackLng: 'en',
      backend: {
      loadPath: path.join(__dirname,'/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json')
      },
      getAsync:false
}, (err, t) => {
      return t;
});
exports.i18n=i18n;
```

For every request I am checking user language via cookies and if not matching I am trying to force the translations to that particular language.

Below is the snippet

```
app.all('*',function(req,res,next){
    var lng = utils.getLanguage;
    lng(req,res,function(data){
        var i18n = utils.i18n;
        i18n(function(i18n){
            var nodeLanguage = i18n.options.lng||i18n.options.fallbackLng;
            if(nodeLanguage == data){
                next();
            }
            else{
                console.log("not same");
                i18n.options.lng = data;
                i18n.init(i18n.options,function(){
                    next();
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This code is working fine for me as i am single user.But If hit the same url in different browsers, it is showing in user selected language but `i18next` is initializing to latest user selected language. For example:-

**case1** : In browser-1, selected **en**,then `i18next.init` method set the language to **en**.

**case2** : In browser-2, selected **fr**, then `i18next.init` method is setting to **fr**.

If I hit the same URL in browser-1, again it is calling i18next.init method.
How to create individual i18next instances to individual users so as to avoid calling init method keep on ? Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the middleware for express: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-express-middleware all you need is there, incl. language detection.